# element_to_be_clickable is giving TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

for the [URL](https://esb.ie/tns/press-centre/2021) I want to induce clicks on the next page button.
The next page button is a `<span>` tag with c`lass attribute = 'fa fa-angle-right'`.

When I try the following, it gives me a `TimeoutException`.

This doesn't work for any page, and even the last page.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'fa fa-angle-right')))
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Selenium` does not support `class name` with **spaces**, you'll have to remove `spaces` and put `.` to make a `css_selector` out of it.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.fa.fa-angle-right')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with css selector:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.fa.fa-angle-right')))
```

Find by class name just for single class.

Comment: could you please explain me why did you put a '.' infront of the class attribute value and used it as a css selector?

Comment: May this link can help https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp @SoumyaPandey